# Dart 2 runtimeType and reified generics - Java Class<T> equivalent

Tags: generics, dart

I am having trouble understanding how generics in Dart work and the documentation did not help me sadly.

---

If I make a class called `Checker` that needs to store it's generic params in some way, I could do it this way (since Dart has `reified` generics):

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}

class Checker<T> {
  bool test(dynamic a) {
    return a is T;
  }
}

main() {
  print(Checker<A>().runtimeType);
  print(Checker<B>().runtimeType);
  print(Checker<String>().runtimeType);

  print(Checker<A>().test(A()));
  print(Checker<A>().test(B()));
  print(Checker<A>().test(""));
}
```

This prints out, just as you would expect:

```
Checker<A>
Checker<B>
Checker<String>
true
true
false
```

---

Here is the issue:

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}

class Checker<T> {
  bool testChecker<C>(Checker<C> a) {
    return C is T;
  }
}
```

The output:

```
false
false
false
```

It seems like, that two reified generics do not work well with each other.

In Java, this is mostly solved by storing a `Class<T>`, which has [`isAssignableFrom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) function that does what it says. In Dart, the `Type` is only an empty abstract class, so there is no use in reading/storing the `runtimeType`, because there is no function to call on it to check assignability relationships. (*Edit.: All classes returned by `runtimeType` are of type `_Type`, so none of their methods can be called.*)

How can I save `runtimeType` in Dart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `testChecker` to `return a is Checker<T>;`, would that be enough for you? That would be checking the *runtime* type of `a`, not the static type of it at the call-point. If you want the latter, you can do `return new Checker<C>() is Checker<T>;`.

It is correct that you should never use `Type` objects for anything like this, so `.runtimeType` is not useful.

The reason the example didn't work was that it did `return C is T;`. The `is` operator takes an object on the left and a type on the right. So, `C` is evaluated as an object, which means it evaluates to an object of type `Type`. Then it checks whether `Type` is a subtype of `T`, which it isn't.
You can't compare type variables directly, you have to compare objects to types. One option is to do `<C>[] is List<T>` - that is: Check that a *ist of `C`* (object) is-a *list of `T`* (type). 
Since I already had a generic class available, I just used `Checker<C>() is Checker<T>` instead.

Comment: You are right with checking the entire type. If I were to replace `Checker<T>` with `Class<T>`, then it seems to be technically the same as if it was Java `Class<T>` as long as I only need `isAssignableFrom`. I could as well create a property then `Checker<T> get checker => Checker<T>();` on any generic type to check if their generic type matches. Dart seems to be okay with the covariance as well, so what you said looks like to be the solution. I will run a couple tests on it and come back later to accept the answer. *(It would be also great to know why the example above did not work.)*

Comment: Thanks for the edit, accepted it. Though it looks like some sort of `TypeMirror` would be preferred in this case probably.

Comment: You can use type mirrors if you have access to `dart:mirrors`. However, that library is not available on the web, and it is not available in Flutter, so it is not a very general solution.

Comment: You saved me from a lot of headaches with that comment. Didn't know there were Dart features not available in Flutter.